# Magento : How to add onchange function in country in Cart page?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, onepage-checkout

I want to add onchange function in select of country in cart page. But country are coming from :

`Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getEstimateCountryId())`

So , How to add onchange function to country on Cart page.

When customer select country then page will reload and display delivery method in dropdown and calculate estimate shipping cost and add in grand total in cart page.

[image]

Comment: there will be form for  estimate shipping calculation in frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml (default rwd) or find in you theme

Comment: Yes , in that form, Country is coming dynamic from this code : `Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getEstimateCountryId())`, So how to edit this ?

Comment: there will be two form but there is no submit button in your attached screenshot

Comment: I want to remove submit and i want to apply submit action on change of country. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the function you are referring. At the end, select html is built by **core/html_select** block

```
public function getCountryHtmlSelect($defValue=null, $name='country_id', $id='country', $title='Country')
{
    Varien_Profiler::start('TEST: '.__METHOD__);
    if (is_null($defValue)) {
        $defValue = $this->getCountryId();
    }
    $cacheKey = 'DIRECTORY_COUNTRY_SELECT_STORE_'.Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
    if (Mage::app()->useCache('config') && $cache = Mage::app()->loadCache($cacheKey)) {
        $options = unserialize($cache);
    } else {
        $options = $this->getCountryCollection()->toOptionArray();
        if (Mage::app()->useCache('config')) {
            Mage::app()->saveCache(serialize($options), $cacheKey, array('config'));
        }
    }
    $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
        ->setName($name)
        ->setId($id)
        ->setTitle(Mage::helper('directory')->__($title))
        ->setClass('validate-select')
        ->setValue($defValue)
        ->setOptions($options)
        ->getHtml();

    Varien_Profiler::stop('TEST: '.__METHOD__);
    return $html;
}
```

The good news for you are **core/html_select** block allows including some extra data, such as you want, using `setExtraParams()` method

For instance, take a look at **Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract::getCountryHtmlSelect()** method

```
public function getCountryHtmlSelect($type)
{
    $countryId = $this->getAddress()->getCountryId();
    if (is_null($countryId)) {
        $countryId = Mage::helper('core')->getDefaultCountry();
    }
    $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
        ->setName($type.'[country_id]')
        ->setId($type.':country_id')
        ->setTitle(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Country'))
        ->setClass('validate-select')
        ->setValue($countryId)
        ->setOptions($this->getCountryOptions());
    if ($type === 'shipping') {
        $select->setExtraParams('onchange="if(window.shipping)shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);"');
    }

    return $select->getHtml();
}
```